# yaml loaded dictionary as strings without quotes and brackets in jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm starting to using Jinja, so maybe the question is trivial and I didn't get (yet) how jinja and flask are working.

What I want to do is to use a yaml file with some values (no too nested, but still a little bit), load it as a dictionary, pass the dictionary values to the jinja template and use flask to render the final html file/s.

This is the super small script I'm using for flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import yaml
import os

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'example.yaml')

app = Flask(__name__)

my_dic = yaml.safe_load(open(file_path))

@app.route("/")
def template_test():
    return render_template('base.html', my_dic=my_dic)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is the jinja template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        {{ my_dic['who']}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this the super silly yaml file content (that should become richer with many other values):

```
who:
  - My string to view
```

Now, this is the output I see in the html:

[image]

as you can see there are `[]` and `'` around the string. I could find a proper way (and I'm sure there is) to render just the string content.

Thanks for any suggestions

**SOLVED**

Thanks to the suggestions. The problem was that the values were read as array and I had to loop them:

```
{% for i in my_dic.who %}
  <p>
    i
  </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that the variable you're trying to render is an array - and jinja is rendering it as such. But you want it to be rendered as a single value - which it's not.

You should try rendering the variable as an array using a for loop: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/

Comment: `      {% for i in my_dic.who %}
          {{ i }}
      {% endfor %}` is not working neither..

Comment: Do you get the same result? Can you share the snippet?

Comment: nope, empty result at all. I just replaced `{{ my_dic['who']}}` with the loop in the other comment

Comment: That means that the key is not being found in this case. my_dic.who is probably evaluating to none. Try using the brackets variant